# Keras Layer Build Error: build() takes 1 Positional Argument but two were given

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

I have the following error in this simple layer:

```
class MyLayer(Layer):

def __init__(self):
    super(MyLayer, self).__init__()

def build(self):
    # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
    self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                  shape=(1)
                                  trainable=True)
    super(MyLayer, self).build() 

def call(self, x):
    return x/self.kernel
```

When I use it as:

```
m = MyLayer()
t = m (input)
```

> Error: build() takes one positional argument but two were given.

Comment: You need to refer [Writing your own Keras layers](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/).

Comment: @giser_yugang it is the same example..

Comment: Every layer in Keras requires an `input_shape` argument which is not present in your `build()` method.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal i put it, i get 'int object is not iterable' error

Comment: You need to iterate like `for i in range( your_int )`. Include that code in your question.\

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal thx, where is iteration needed in the above code...i just added input_shape argument to build()...

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal plz post your comment as answer, issue got fixed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each layer in a Keras layer requires a `input_shape` argument. Add it to your `build()` method.